# How to create alert for logged errors?

Tags: .net, grafana, grafana-loki

I have a stream of log messages in Loki, and I want to create an alert if error is logged.

Here is the query I wrote for the alert

```
sum by (app) (count_over_time({app="my-app"} | json | Level="Error" or Level="Critical" or Level="Fatal"[5m])) > 0
```

However, when I try to preview, I get the error:

> invalid format of evaluation results for the alert definition Failures: looks like time series data, only reduced data can be alerted on.

What should I do to make grafna happy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reduce the query first and set the right alert condition. Documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/unified-alerting/alerting-rules/create-grafana-managed-rule/):

[image]

Comment: It absolutely does not follow from the doc that reduction is possible with expression part only. Why does it even allow omitting expression part, if 4semantically it's mandatory?